# Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api

i have a problem... i try to get json api in **"http://api.master18.tiket.com/search/autocomplete/hotel?q=mah&token=90d2fad44172390b11527557e6250e50&secretkey=83e2f0484edbd2ad6fc9888c1e30ea44&output=json"**

when i try to offline mode(this means i copy that json API in notepad and call it in my localhost) with this code...

```
function getLast(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost/tickets/json/api_airport.json",
            type:'GET',
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){console.log(data.results.result[1].category);}
        });
    }
```

it runs perfectly.:)

but when i try to real url ("**http://api.master18.tiket.com/search/autocomplete/hotel?q=mah&token=90d2fad44172390b11527557e6250e50&secretkey=83e2f0484edbd2ad6fc9888c1e30ea44&output=json**") with this code:

```
$.ajax({
            url:"http://api.master18.tiket.com/search/autocomplete/hotel?q=mah&token=90d2fad44172390b11527557e6250e50&secretkey=83e2f0484edbd2ad6fc9888c1e30ea44&output=json",
            type:'GET',
            crossDomain:true,
            beforeSend: function(x) {
                if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                    x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
                }
            },
            success:function(data){console.log("Success");}
        });
```

then in my google chrome javascript console,there is an error like this :
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.master18.tiket.com/search/autocomplete/hotel?q=mah&token=90d2fad44172390b11527557e6250e50&secretkey=83e2f0484edbd2ad6fc9888c1e30ea44&output=json. Origin (http://localhost) is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

i know, it must be cross domain problem, can someone help me?
nb:some pieces of code, i got from stack overflow community....thank you :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You've got two ways to go forward:

## JSONP

---

If this API supports `JSONP`, the easiest way to fix this issue is to add `&callback` to the end of the URL. You can also try `&callback=`. If that doesn't work, it means the API does not support `JSONP`, so you must try the other solution.

## Proxy Script

---

You can create a proxy script on the same domain as your website in order to avoid the cross-origin issues. This will only work with HTTP URLs, not HTTPS URLs, but it shouldn't be too difficult to modify if you need that.

```
<?php
// File Name: proxy.php
if (!isset($_GET['url'])) {
    die(); // Don't do anything if we don't have a URL to work with
}
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
$url = 'http://' . str_replace('http://', '', $url); // Avoid accessing the file system
echo file_get_contents($url); // You should probably use cURL. The concept is the same though
```

Then you just call this script with jQuery. Be sure to `urlencode` the URL.

```
$.ajax({
    url      : 'proxy.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.master18.tiket.com%2Fsearch%2Fautocomplete%2Fhotel%3Fq%3Dmah%26token%3D90d2fad44172390b11527557e6250e50%26secretkey%3D83e2f0484edbd2ad6fc9888c1e30ea44%26output%3Djson',
    type     : 'GET',
    dataType : 'json'
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data.results.result[1].category); // Do whatever you want here
});
```

## The Why

---

You're getting this error because of XMLHttpRequest same origin policy, which basically boils down to a restriction of ajax requests to URLs with a different port, domain or protocol. This restriction is in place to prevent cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

[More Information](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)

Our solutions by pass these problems in different ways.

`JSONP` uses the ability to point script tags at JSON (wrapped in a javascript function) in order to receive the JSON. The JSONP page is interpreted as javascript, and executed. The JSON is passed to your specified function.

The proxy script works by tricking the browser, as you're actually requesting a page on the same origin as your page. The actual cross-origin requests happen server-side.

Comment: i already use &callback=? but there is same...it means the api can't support jsonp :)

Comment: Yes, so try the proxy script :)

Comment: hey friend...proxy script is working perfectly...thankyou sooo much...

wohooooo!!! :)

Comment: What is there to explain, it is very simple what a proxy does, just so this script, the details are not important. Minor thing: You forgot the closing tag ?> in the PHP script.

Comment: Pages that just contain PHP do not need the `?>` tag. In fact, it's [discouraged](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)

Comment: I'm using django-rest-framework, just tried the json-p way but it doesn't work. I'd like to try the proxy script, but I need one in django not in PHP. Anyone has one ready to use?

Comment: @AndreaGrandi They're really easy to make. Just fetch the contents of the page with `urllib2`, and output it however you normally would with Django. I've never used Python for the web, so I can't really help you out with that. Good luck though.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this (for development) with a simple nginx proxy...

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
server {
  listen 80;
  root /path/to/Development/dir;
  index index.html;

  # from your example
  location /search {
    proxy_pass http://api.master18.tiket.com;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

a thorough reading of [jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain) seems to indicate that the server you are querying is returning a header string that prohibits cross-domain json requests.  Check the headers of the response you are receiving to see if the  Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is set, and whether its value restricts cross-domain requests to the local host.