# Read xml from php pages by Jquery

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xml>
  <weather>
   <location>Wonderland</location>
   <temp>20</temp>
  </weather>
 </xml>
```

My javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

 $.ajax({

  type: "GET",

  url: "https://..../Weather.php",

  dataType: "xml",

   success: function(xml) {

    $(xml).find('weather').each(function(){

     var location = $(this).find("location").text();

     var temp = $(this).find("temp").text();

     $("#footer").append(temp+location);

      });

     }

     });

   });

  // ]]>

 </script>
```

Can somebody please show me where I was wrong?

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you run your code? error?

Comment: i ran it but i didn't see value from xml file, i tried printing something after success: function(xml)  but i didn't show up

Comment: you should check your ajax url manually with your browser or with console.log(xml)

Comment: actually, the url on a ftp server and I just ran my web page locally, will that cause problems?

Comment: Yes, you could run into cross-origin errors. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683530/origin-http-localhost-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin/12683591#comment17119419_12683591

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at [Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683530/origin-http-localhost-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin/12683591#comment17119419_12683591) - You may be running into cross-origin issues.