# JQuery AJAX doesn't get to success call back function

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

Here is my jQuery Ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

          $("#submitService").click(function(){  
              alert("Before ajax");
            $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk",
               headers: {"accept": "application/json"},
             success: function (dataItem) {
                alert("Success..");
            },
             complete: function (dataItem) {
                alert("Completed");
            },
              error: function (dataItem) {
                 alert("Error in making engine call."+dataItem);
              }
             });
             alert("After ajax");

            });                 //click()
      });
```

When my button is clicked it enters to [complete] and [error] call back methods but NOT to "success" call back method. How can I see what the error is?

I tried to curl the same statement and I get a valid response:

```
curl "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk" -H "accept: application/json"
```

I'm using jQuery 1.7.2

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<spring:url value="/resources/jquery/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"/>'></script>
```

In FireBug it shows that request with 200 OK, but no response body. But I see response body when I do it via curl.

What could be the issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I guess, it is URL encode problem.  Replace  comma `,` with encode `%2C`

```
url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London%2Cuk"
```

Comment: thanks! but still success call back is not being called even if i replace , with %2C

Comment: Yes, You have `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin` problem.

Comment: looks like i need to change the remote server config to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * as part of the response. Right? Assuming that I have a control on the server. Otherwise how can i resolve this?

Comment: This link may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683530/origin-http-localhost-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Answer (score 1):

Cancel the click event

```
$("#submitService").click(function(e){  
    e.preventDeault();
    ...
```

and let jQuery do the proper encoding of the URL

```
type: "GET",
url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather",
data: {q : "London,uk" },
```

and hopefully the service and your browser both support CORS since this is a [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) issue.

Comment: This one is not working too. I added a param e to the function then e.preventDefault(); And separeted the data part of the query from the url. Still success is not called.

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice there are no Allow-Access-Origin in Api call?

I got this on chrome

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://jquery.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I think you have a cross site scripting issue.

Comment: Thanks Nitin, I guess there is no work around this. I am planning to make a request to my server and make the call from my server instead of from javascript. My understanding is the constraint is only for js making calls and not java making calls from the server. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

change application/json to application/x-www-form-urlencoded